# reshape dataframe according to duration

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to re-shape a dataframe to a dataframe with below rules:

1. Add a row under current ts with ts + dur,copy other columns
2. Add a None row to the next row.

example:

```
import pandas as pd
import itertools

def segments(df):
    start = df['ts']
    end = start + df['dur']
    lst = list(zip(start, end, itertools.cycle([None])))
    return lst

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'ts':   [1, 5, 10 ],
    'dur':  [1, 2, 1 ],
    'typ':  [0, 1, 0]
})
print(df)
lst = segments(df)
print(lst)
```

current output is a list:

```
   ts  dur  typ
0   1    1    0
1   5    2    1
2  10    1    0
[(1, 2, None), (5, 7, None), (10, 11, None)]
```

expected output:

```
   ts  typ
0  1    0
1  2    0
2  NA   NA
3  5    1
4  7    1
5  NA   NA
6  10   0
7  11   0
8  NA   NA
```

Comment: Interesting problem, but what's the question? Like, if you're stuck, what are you stuck on? You might want to read [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/4518341) See [ask] for tips like how to write a good title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```py
df["ts"] = df.apply(lambda row: [row["ts"], row["ts"] + row["dur"], np.nan], axis=1)
df = df.explode("ts").drop(columns="dur").reset_index(drop=True)
df["typ"] = np.where(df["ts"].isna(), np.nan, df["typ"])

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
    ts  typ
0    1  0.0
1    2  0.0
2  NaN  NaN
3    5  1.0
4    7  1.0
5  NaN  NaN
6   10  0.0
7   11  0.0
8  NaN  NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, no need for your custom function, just duplicate the DataFrame 3 times with small modifications, [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) and [`sort_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

```
out = (pd.concat([df[['ts', 'typ']],
                  df.eval('ts = ts+dur')[['ts', 'typ']],
                  df[[]]
                 ])
         .sort_index(ignore_index=True)
      )
```

Output:

```
     ts  typ
0   1.0  0.0
1   2.0  0.0
2   NaN  NaN
3   5.0  1.0
4   7.0  1.0
5   NaN  NaN
6  10.0  0.0
7  11.0  0.0
8   NaN  NaN
```

If you have a very large DataFrame you can replace the sorting step by:

```
N = len(df)
a = np.arange(N)
order = np.tile(3*a, N)+np.repeat(a, 3)

out = (pd.concat([df[['ts', 'typ']],
                  df.eval('ts = ts+dur')[['ts', 'typ']],
                  df[[]]
                 ])
         .iloc[order].reset_index(drop=True)
      )
```

Comment: I got a similar solution: `df.drop(columns='dur').pipe(lambda d: pd.concat([d, d.assign(ts=df.eval('ts + dur')) ...` It should be more flexible by dropping the column you don't want instead of selecting the columns you do.

Comment: @wjandrea yes that's a fair point, I guess it depends on the number of extra columns, in any case the important logic is the `concat`. (And thanks for the typo fix).